# Radio Buttons React.js handler function

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I've created a React component that should show a form with different fields depending on which type (= mode in the code) of address the user will.
The user can choose the address type with the help of two radio buttons.

The initial html is looking good: the person type is selected. Also the second step is good: if I click company the company address type is set and the correct fields are shown. But if I click back the person mode, no event is thrown anymore.

```cjsx
ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON = 1
ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY = 2

EditAddressComp = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    {
      mode: ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON
    }
  handleRBAM: (e, mode)-> # handle radio button address mode
    @setState
      mode: mode
    console.log 'a',mode
  handleRBAM_: (_mode)-> # returns handler
    console.log 'b',_mode
    self = @
    return (e)->
      self.handleRBAM(e,_mode)
  render: ->
    <form className="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div className="form-group">
        <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <label className="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="addressMode" id="addressMode1"
            onclick={@handleRBAM_ ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON}
            defaultChecked={@state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON}
            value={ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON}/> Person
        </label>
        <label className="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="addressMode" id="addressMode2"
            onclick={@handleRBAM_ ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY}
            defaultChecked={@state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY}
            value={ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY}/> Company
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      {
        if @state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY
          <EditAddressComp.Company />
        else if @state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON
          <EditAddressComp.Person />
        else
          <span/>
      }
      <div className="form-group">
        <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>


EditAddressComp.Company = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">Name:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" 
          placeholder="Enter name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">Name 2:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name2" 
          placeholder="Enter Name 2"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

EditAddressComp.Person = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">First name:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="firstname" 
          placeholder="Enter first name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lastname" 
          placeholder="Enter last name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea about what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON = '1'
ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY = '2'

EditAddressComp = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    {
      mode: ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON
    }
  handleRBAM: (e)-> # handle radio button address mode
    @setState
      mode: e.currentTarget.value
  render: ->
    <form className="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div className="form-group">
        <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <label className="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="addressMode" id="addressMode1"
            onChange=@handleRBAM
            defaultChecked={@state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON}
            value={ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON}/> Person
        </label>
        <label className="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="addressMode" id="addressMode2"
            onChange=@handleRBAM
            defaultChecked={@state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY}
            value={ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY}/> Company
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      {
        if @state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_COMPANY
          <EditAddressComp.Company />
        else if @state.mode is ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON
          <EditAddressComp.Person />
        else
          <span/>
      }
      <div className="form-group">
        <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>


EditAddressComp.Company = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">Name:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name"
          placeholder="Enter name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">Name 2:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name2"
          placeholder="Enter Name 2"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

EditAddressComp.Person = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">First name:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="firstname"
          placeholder="Enter first name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name:</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lastname"
          placeholder="Enter last name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

1. *React* seems to digest only *onChange* and not *onclick*.
2. `ADDRESS_MODE_PERSON = '1'` should be defined as string and not number (otherwise the comparison fails)